# Need help understanding Solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I'm just getting started with Nutch and Solr.  I ran the crawl once with just one seed URL.
I ran this command:

`bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5`

Everything goes fine and I'm assuming Solr indexes the pages?  So how do I go about searching now?  I went here **localhost:8983/solr/admin/** but when I put a search query and click search I get this:

```
HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /solr/select/.
Reason: undefined field text
```

I also tried an example from the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/doc-files/tutorial.html) but when I run this command:

`java -jar post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml`

I get this:

```
SimplePostTool: version 1.4
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file solr.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #400 ERROR: [doc=SOLR1000] unknown field 'name'
```

My ultimate goal is to somehow add this data into Accumulo and use it for a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Nutch 1.4 or up. If that is the case, you need to change the type of the fields you added in the solr/conf/schema.xml file from "text" to "text_general", without the quotes.

I am working towards a similar goal right now and have used that fix to at least get solr working properly, although I still cannot get solr to search the indexed sites. Hope this helps, let me know if you get it working.